# VirtualHost configuration

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I need to configure two name-based virtual hosts in my Ubuntu PC. If I type the address `http://mypage1` in browser, it should display my first customized html page and if I type the address `http://mypage2`, it should display my second customized html page. I tried out the following:

1. installed apache
2. created a file `mypage1` inside `sites-available` with the contents as follows:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mypage1
    ServerAlias http://mypage1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mypage1/html
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. created a similar file `mypage2` inside `sites-available`
4. ran the commands `a2ensite mypage1` and `a2ensite mypage2` to generate soft links inside sites-enabled.
5. restarted apache using `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

After doing the above steps, when I type `mypage1` in firefox, I get dns_unresolved_hostname error.

Kindly help me how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

DNS unresolved means exactly what it said! It could not find the DNS entries for 'servers' called mypage1 or mypage2.

Add them to you /etc/hosts file like

```
127.0.0.1 mypage1 mypage2
```

If you are successful then you will probably get a different error, then you can start looking into virtual hosts configuration

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you should set a NameVirtualHost for whatever IP(s) you intend to serve the files from.  (If you don't, Apache will usually ignore the server name and just use whatever site is defined/included first.)

Also, make sure "mypage1" and "mypage2" are actual, valid domain names, or put them in /etc/hosts.  Apache's knowing about them doesn't automatically make them known anywhere outside Apache -- especially to your machine's DNS resolver.