# Problems configuring VirtualHost in Apache2 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, virtualhost

After reading through various tutorials [1] I still can't get my VirtualHost settings to work as desired. I'm getting a `403 Forbidden` when I try to use a VirtualHost with a directory below my user directory as its `DocumentRoot`.

#### What I've done so far

- Created file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/workspace` with following content:

  ```
  NameVirtualHost *:80
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName project-site
      DocumentRoot /home/user/Workspace/project/site
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- Edited file `/etc/hosts` now yielding:

  ```
  127.0.0.1   localhost
  127.0.1.1   my-machine

  # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
  ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
  fe00::0 ip6-localnet
  ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
  ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
  ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

  # VirtualHosts added by me
  127.0.0.1   project-site
  ```
- Enabled virtual hosts using `sudo a2ensite workspace`
- Restarted Apache using `sudo services apache2 restart`
- Tried opening `http://project-site` and `http://project-site/test.html` (where `test.html` is present in `/home/user/Workspace/project/site/`) in my webbrowser

#### What happens

- Restarting Apache I get the following messages on the command line:

  ```
  * Restarting web server apache2
  apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
  [Sun May 13 10:33:37 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
  [ OK ]
  ```
- Opening either `http://project-site` or `http://project-site/test.html` a "403 Forbidden" is served.

#### What should happen

I'd like to have the contents of `/home/user/Workspace/project/site` being served when I browse to `http://project-site`.

#### What I learned so far

From reading similar questions on this site I learned that this is probably a permission problem [2]. Files in `/home/user/Workspace/project/site` might not be readable by `www-data`. But how do I know or correct this?

Furthermore `.htaccess` files were mentioned [3] being located in

```
/home/.htaccess
/home/user/.htacces
[...]
/home/user/path/to/project/.htaccess
```

and possibly not readable. I never created them, I don't want them, will I need them?

The second answer to another question [4] made me use `NameVirtualHost` responsible for the warning on restart of Apache. Is it necessary and if, how do I use it properly?

**Any help is much appreciated! Tell me, if you need to know anything else to locate the problem.**

---

Ressources

1. `http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/apache-virtual-host/, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html, http://mintarticles.com/read/software-articles/multiple-virtual-hosts-in-xampplampp-in-ubuntu,977/, http://www.pgorecki.pl/content/virtual-host-na-localho%C5%9Bcie-apache-ubuntu, ...`
2. [Apache VirtualHost 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959189/apache-virtualhost-403-forbidden)
3. [Ubuntu, Apache, virtualhost and Access forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880258/ubuntu-apache-virtualhost-and-access-forbidden)
4. [VirtualHost configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674460/virtualhost-configuration)

Comment: Hope this helps
Video http://youtu.be/QaZBly7_0zo http://wilson18.com/how-to/linux-net...-server-12-04/

Comment: +1 your question solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following solution, not satisfying me, but solving my primary problem. Indeed it is about permissions like suggested in [1]. My `/home/user` directory was not accessible to the webserver. In order to grant minimal possible permissions I used

```
chmod 701 /home/user
```

to make it accessible. Additionally I recursively gave group ownership to `www-data` for the webroot of the virtual host like recommended in [2], but I'm not sure, whether this is necessary.

```
sudo chown -R user:www-data /home/user/Workspace/project/site
sudo chmod -R g+s /home/user/Workspace/project/site
```

I'm going to ask for a more elegant solution in a separate question.

Regarding the other problems mentioned, I found out the following with the help of [3] besides other resources:

- It is not necessary and may cause an error to have `NameVirtualHost *:80` in the virtual hosts description, if it appears in one of apaches other configuration files.
- To let apache know about its fully qualified domain name being `localhost` one creates a file `/etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn` with content `ServerName localhost`.

---

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7576526/948404
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9133067/948404
3. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP